Support of a continuous distribution always contains open interval?
For a real-valued random variable $X$ with continuous distribution function $F$, its support is defined as:
$$\mathrm{supp}(X)=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}\mid \forall \epsilon>0 : F(x-\epsilon)<F(x+\epsilon)\right\}.$$
Does the continuity of $F$ imply that there always exists a (nonempty) open interval contained in $\mathrm{supp}(X)$? Intuitively, I think this holds true, but I'm struggling to show it. Any hint will be helpful. Thanks!

No, the Cantor function is a counterexample, where $\operatorname{supp}(X)$ is the Cantor set and has empty interior.


An answer to the question from the comments:

What if we assume absolute continuity? Does it suffice to guarantee the existence of an open interval contained in the support?

Answer: no, it is still insufficient.
Let $\mathcal{D}$ denote a fat Cantor set, which is a subset of $[0, 1]$ with positive Lebesgue measure but empty interior. Take a random variable $X$ corresponding to the distribution function
$$F(x) = \frac{\lambda \big( \mathcal{D} \cap (-\infty, x] \big)}{\lambda(\mathcal{D})}.$$
Clearly $F$ is Lipschitz with constant $\frac{1}{\lambda(\mathcal{D})}$, so it is absolutely continuous. It remains to prove that $\operatorname{supp}(X) = \mathcal{D}$, thus a set with empty interior.
Recall that $\mathcal{D}$ is defined as
$$\mathcal{D} = \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} \bigcup_{j=1}^{2^n} I_n^{(j)}$$
for some adequately constructed disjoint closed intervals $I_n^{(j)}$ with diameters approaching $0$.
Take any $a \in \mathcal{D}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Then for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the interval $(a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon)$ contains one of $I_n^{(j)}$. In particular
$$F(a+\varepsilon) - F(a-\varepsilon) = \frac{\lambda \big( \mathcal{D} \cap (a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon] \big)}{\lambda(\mathcal{D})} \geqslant \frac{\lambda \big( \mathcal{D} \cap I_n^{(j)} \big)}{\lambda(\mathcal{D})} = \frac{1}{2^n},$$
hence $a \in \operatorname{supp}(X)$.
On the other hand, take $a \notin \mathcal{D}$. Since $\mathcal{D}$ is closed, we can find $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\mathcal{D} \cap [a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon] = \varnothing$. Thus
$$F(a+\varepsilon) - F(a-\varepsilon) = \frac{\lambda \big( \mathcal{D} \cap (a-\varepsilon, a+\varepsilon] \big)}{\lambda(\mathcal{D})} = 0$$
and so $a \notin \operatorname{supp}(X)$.

You meany 'empty interior' right ?

Of course, thanks.

Thanks, this is helpful!! What if we assume absolute continuity? Does it suffice to guarantee the existence of an open interval contained in the support? But I can ask this in a different thread

@cliu55 An equivalent construction with the fat Cantor set in place of the Cantor set is a counterexample. But sure, feel free to ask in a new thread if you feel more explanation would be helpful.

@cliu55 Actually I have included an expanded answer to your question about absolute continuity. It turns out even Lipschitz continuity of $F$ does not guarantee that the support will have non-empty interior.

@Adayah This answer is really quick and helpful! Thanks a lot!!
